# Slow enumeration of schemas and tables in a largish database

Tags: postgresql, performance

We have a Postgresql 8.4.8 database server on a Debian system with a database that has 500+ schemas with roughly 300+ tables each. The schemas and tables are created by scripts, we cannot influence the process much short of deleting unnecessary schemas every now and then. Perhaps there were 5000+ schemas during the lifetime of this database, of which 4500- are gone now.

Opening the database using pgAdmin3 takes ages. Opening a schema takes ages. Autocompletion in `psql` is horribly slow. This does not happen with "small" databases. I have tried `VACUUM ANALYZE pg_tables`, but this is not supported.

Are there some cleanup tasks that need to be carried out to handle this situation? Or perhaps there is a tuning parameter that can be set? An index on a system table missing or outdated?

As a side question: Is it possible to group several schemas so that there is yet another hierarchy level between "database" and "table"?

Comment: +1 Have you tried to dump-restore the database? Maybe this can cleanup things a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can also be a shortcoming of [pgAdmin](http://pgadmin.org/). There have been a number of improvements for recent versions. Which one do you use? 1.14.2 is the current version (as of 2012-05-21).

Are queries from the command line interface `psql` slow, too?

Apart from that, you need to keep [vacuuming](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/routine-vacuuming.html) all your tables in the database, not just `pg_tables`. I would strongly advice to enable the [auto vacuuming daemon](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM).

Also, [`pg_tables`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/view-pg-tables.html) is not relevant at all. It is a system **view** to implement the SQL standard information schema. The relevant system tables would be `pg_namespace`, `pg_class`, `pg_attribute` and others. But it is pointless to target just one of them. For your kind of setup you need to be vacuuming the whole catalog. And it is **very** advisable to vacuum all of your database on a regular basis anyway. So, let me repeat: use `autovacuum`.

For starters, you can run in a Debian shell:

```
vacuumdb -afz
reindexdb -a
reindexdb -s
```

The last line targets system tables for possible bloat of indexes in the catalog in particular. See `man reindexdb` or the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/app-reindexdb.html).

Finally, another option would be to upgrade to PostgreSQL 9.1. There have been a number of improvements for `VACUUM` and `ANALYZE` (among many others). In particular `VACUUM FULL` has been rewritten for 9.0 and does a much better job now.

Comment: Thank you. We are using pgAdmin3 from ubuntugis-unstable, which is currently in version 1.14.0. -- Which query should I check for performance? Selecting from data tables doesn't seem to be that slow. -- I will need `root` rights on the server machine in order to edit the configuration for enabling autovacuum, right? In which file will I find the relevant entries? Do I need to fiddle with `cron`, too? -- For `vacuumdb` and `reindexdb` to fix the system catalog, I run it as `postgres` database user, right? Is it advisable to enable password access for that user?

Comment: I have found out that `-a` selects all databases. In our case, we have only one database and use `-d dbname`. Most of these operations can be done as standard user. I also found the autovacuum settings in `postgresql.conf`. So, my questions in the comment above are more or less solved :-)

Comment: @user946850: You shouldn't need the root user, the postgres user should be able to do almost everything. Some (non-invasive) things can be done with any user. You already found `postgresql.conf`, that's the one.

Comment: Thanks again. Indeed, it seems that pgAdmin3 issues an expensive query when opening a schema node. Clearly a bug, it's even in the dev version. -- Concerning autovacuum -- isn't it supposed to be on by default?

Comment: @user946850: In recent versions autovacuum is on by default. *Should* be the case for 8.4. But since you mentioned manual vacuuming, I wanted to cover all bases. With autovacuum on (and appropriate settings), manual vacuuming is largely irrelevant. There have been a couple of improvements and fixes since 8.4, though.